# QGIS defaults new layers to not defined CRS (EPSG 7791)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, default

Since I updated QGIS to 3.12 whenever I load a new layer into QGIS it sets the CRS to EPSG 7791. The same CRS is used as default when I want to export a layer, I always have to change the CRS from EPSG 7791 to my desired EPSG 3044 before I can export the layer. I never used EPSG 7791 before. I have set the Option under "Settings" -> "Options" -> "CRS"  to EPSG 3044. The project CRS is also 3044, so I really do not understand where  EPSG 7791 comes from. Anyone experienced the same issue?

Edit: Even after complete uninstall (and removing the remaining "profiles" folder) and reinstall the issue remains.